# Closure with generic parameters

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble writing the following function as a closure

```swift
func myfunc<S where S: MyProtocol, S: MySuperClass>(param: S) { ... }
```

I tried

```
let myClosure = {<S where S: MyProtocol, S: MySuperClass>(param: S) in ... }
```

, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe what you're asking for can't make sense (having nothing to do with Swift). While I'm interested in being proven wrong, I don't believe this could be reasonably created in any strongly typed language. (EDIT: continuing my research, I believe this would be possible in a language with first-class polymorphism, but I am not aware of any general-use languages that actually have this feature.)

```
let myClosure = {<S where S: MyProtocol, S: MySuperClass>(param: S) in ... }
```

What type would you expect `myClosure` to be? A generic creates an abstract type. It does not become a real type until it is specialized. So `myClosure` would be of an abstract type itself. That's like asking for an instance of an abstract class. The whole point of "abstract" is you can't construct one. The best you could say would be that `myClosure` would itself be a type that you would need to instantiate into a real instance (but then `let` doesn't make any sense; you don't `let` types).

When you wrap this in a `struct`, what you're really doing is creating an abstract type that you will specialize into a real type when you create an instance.

Now what would make sense IMO (but appears currently to be impossible), is this:

```
typealias Mapping<S> = S -> S
let identity: Mapping<Int> = { return $0 }
```

That makes sense because you're defining an abstract type (`Mapping`), but then instantiating a concrete type `Mapping<Int>`. Unfortunately, `typealias` does not appear to support generics at this point, so a `struct` is probably the best tool we have.

---

Note that while `typealias` is a bust, it is clearly possible to specialize function variables themselves. This isn't a closure, I know, but may be useful in some of the same situations.

```
func Identity<T>(i:T) -> T {
  return i
}

let identityInt:(Int -> Int) = Identity
identityInt(1) // => 1
```

Using this to explore the problem of abstract types a little more, consider:

```
func Identity<T>(i:T) -> T { return i }
let x = Identity
```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
error: cannot convert the expression's type '(T) -> T' to type '(T) -> T'
```

That's because the type `(T) -> T` is not a concrete type, so you can't have one called `x`. Compare that to `identityInt`, which I explicitly specialized into a concrete type, and then could construct.

Comment: I believe you are correct :) Thank you for a very thorough answer

Comment: Haskell is a strongly-typed general-use language that supports this kind of polymorphism.

Answer (score 6):

You could try wrapping your closure within a struct that declares the generic type. Something like:

```
struct ClosureWrapper<S where S: MyClass, S: MyProtocol> {
    let myClosure = {(param: S) in ... }
}
```

Of course, at this point your closure may as well be a normal function :P

Comment: I ended up with a similar solution creating a static function on a struct however it feels like more of a workaround. Didn't know you could put generics in the struct definition though :D