# is it possible to create a generic closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, generics, swift, closures

```
func myfunc<T>(i:T) -> T {
    return i
}
```

is it possible to make this generic function a closure?

```
let myfunc = { <T>(i:T) -> T in
    return i
}
```

this doesn't work...

Comment: Similar (same?) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401584/generics-as-parameters-to-a-closure-in-swift.

Comment: Generics cannot be used with closures. The answer linked by @MartinR provides a workaround. I don't think this question is a duplicate, because the other question is about making a closure with generics work, whereas this is an explicit question whether generics can be used or not.

Comment: I believe the answer is that this doesn't work because it actually makes no sense (having nothing to do with Swift in particular). `myfunc` would be of an abstract type, which is the same as trying to construct an abstract class. I discuss more in an answer to the question @MartinR links.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, because variables and expressions can't be generic. There are only generic functions and generic types.

---

To clarify: In some languages you can have types with a universal quantifier, like `forall a. a -> a`. But in Swift, types cannot have a universal quantifier. So expressions and values cannot be themselves generic. Function declarations and type declarations can be generic, but when you use such a generic function or an instance of such a generic type, some type (which could be a real type or a type variable) is chosen as the type argument, and thereafter the value you get is no longer itself generic.

Comment: I agree with Rob, in the sense that it should make sense to use `typealias` in conjunction with a closure to define a generic closure type

Comment: In most programming languages, generic function arguments are effectively just function arguments with values baked in at compile-time.  So it would mean that the possible values for the generic argument are evaluated at compile-time instead of just used at run-time (like normal function/closure arguments). The advantage would be the ability to parameterize a closure with types that need to be evaluated at compile-time, e.g. `StringLiteralConvertible`.  I think your confusion lies in thinking about the variable or expression as generic; rather, it's the closure which is generic.

Comment: How about this one ?
    typealias ResultClosure<T> = (ResultCode, String?, T?) -> Void

    func loginUser(userName: String, password: String, resultHandler: ResultClosure<TokenModel>?)
It is generic and have compile time type check

Comment: Variables are allowed to be generic in C++.

Answer (score 12):

Probably you need something like this.

Type declaration:

```
typealias ResultClosure<T> = (ResultCode, String?, T?) -> Void
```

Function declaration:

```
func loginUser(userName: String, password: String, resultHandler: ResultClosure<TokenModel>?)
```

Usage:

```
    NetConnector.shared.loginUser(userName: userName ?? "", password: password ?? "") { (code, message, data) in
        self.display?.unlockScreen()
        if code == .success {
            if let activeToken = data {
                AppData.shared.userToken = activeToken
            }
            self.display?.showHome()
        } else {
            self.display?.showError(errorMessage: message)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, but it won't work using type constraint and defining an object property with that type (typealias)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, variables in Swift cannot be generic, so creating a closure, whose generic types are specified by the caller is not possible. However, there are workarounds:

With [SE-253](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0253-callable.md), it is possible to make arbitrary (nominal) types callable. So instead of declaring a generic closure, we can declare a (non-generic) struct that has a generic `callAsFunction` method:

```swift
struct MyFunc {
    func callAsFunction<T>(_ i: T) -> T {
        return i
    }
}
```

Now, we can declare a non-generic variable that we can call with a generic value:

```swift
let myFunc = MyFunc()
let x = myFunc(42) // -> Int
let y = myFunc("foo") // -> String
```

Note that this workaround doesn't apply to all situations, but it can be helpful in some.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some alternative way , you can use Anyobject in your closure and pass any values to your method .

```
typealias genericCompletion<T:AnyObject> = ((Bool,T,String) -> Void)
struct Student {
    var name:String = "Kishore"
    var age : String = "125"
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.createAGenericReturn { (success, object, message) in

        }

        self.createStructGeneric { (success, student, message) in

        }

    }


    func createAGenericReturn(callback:@escaping(genericCompletion<AnyObject>)){
        callback(true,434.433 as AnyObject,"kishoreTest")
    }

    func createStructGeneric(callback:@escaping(genericCompletion<AnyObject>)){
        callback(true,Student.init() as AnyObject,"kishoreTest")
    }

}
```

Here you can see I mentioned Generic as Anyobject **typealias genericCompletion = ((Bool,T,String) -> Void)** , So you can pass any values to it .

Comment: Interesting solution, making use of polymorphism. However, this weakens the type checker, also the code  that needs to implement the generic closure will have to do a lot of downcases if it will want to support multiple types.