# Swift Generics: Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type

Tags: swift, generics

Here is my code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
}

class A: SomeProtocol {
}

func f1<T: SomeProtocol>(ofType: T.Type, listener: (T?) -> Void) {
}

func f2<T: SomeProtocol>(ofType: T.Type, listener: ([T]?) -> Void) {
}

func g() {
    let l1: (SomeProtocol?) -> Void = ...
    let l2: ([SomeProtocol]?) -> Void = ...
    f1(ofType: A.self, listener: l1) // NO ERROR
    f2(ofType: A.self, listener: l2) // COMPILE ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '([SomeProtocol]?) -> Void' to expected argument type '([_]?) -> Void'
}
```

What is the problem with the second closure having an argument of an **array** of generic type objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Swift 4.1 Update

This is a bug that was fixed [in this pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13138), which will make it into the release of Swift 4.1. Your code now compiles as expected in a 4.1 snapshot.

---

#### Pre Swift 4.1

This just looks like you're just stretching the compiler too far.

- It can deal with conversions from arrays of sub-typed elements to arrays of super-typed elements, e.g `[A]` to `[SomeProtocol]` – this is covariance. It's worth noting that arrays have always been an edge case here, as arbitrary generics are invariant. Certain collections, such as `Array`, just [get special treatment from the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37188580/2976878) allowing for covariance.
- It can deal with conversions of functions with super-typed parameters to functions with sub-typed parameters, e.g `(SomeProtocol) -> Void` to `(A) -> Void` – this is contravariance.

However it appears that it currently cannot do both in one go (but really it should be able to; feel free to [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org)).

For what it's worth, this has nothing to do with generics, the following reproduces the same behaviour:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}
class A : SomeProtocol {}

func f1(listener: (A) -> Void) {}
func f2(listener: ([A]) -> Void) {}
func f3(listener: () -> [SomeProtocol]) {}

func g() {

    let l1: (SomeProtocol) -> Void = { _ in }        
    f1(listener: l1) // NO ERROR

    let l2: ([SomeProtocol]) -> Void = { _ in }
    f2(listener: l2) 
    // COMPILER ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '([SomeProtocol]) -> Void' to
    // expected argument type '([A]) -> Void'

    // it's the same story for function return types
    let l3: () -> [A] = { [] }
    f3(listener: l3)
    // COMPILER ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '() -> [A]' to
    // expected argument type '() -> [SomeProtocol]'
}
```

Until fixed, one solution in this case is to simply use a closure expression to act as a trampoline between the two function types:

```
// converting a ([SomeProtocol]) -> Void to a ([A]) -> Void.
// compiler infers closure expression to be of type ([A]) -> Void, and in the
// implementation, $0 gets implicitly converted from [A] to [SomeProtocol].
f2(listener: { l2($0) })

// converting a () -> [A] to a () -> [SomeProtocol].
// compiler infers closure expression to be of type () -> [SomeProtocol], and in the
// implementation, the result of l3 gets implicitly converted from [A] to [SomeProtocol]
f3(listener: { l3() })
```

And, applied to your code:

```
f2(ofType: A.self, listener: { l2($0) })
```

This works because the compiler infers the closure expression to be of type `([T]?) -> Void`, which can be passed to `f2`. In the implementation of the closure, the compiler then performs an implicit conversion of `$0` from `[T]?` to `[SomeProtocol]?`.

And, [as Dominik is hinting at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44991267/2976878), this trampoline could also be done as an additional overload of `f2`:

```
func f2<T : SomeProtocol>(ofType type: T.Type, listener: ([SomeProtocol]?) -> Void) {
    // pass a closure expression of type ([T]?) -> Void to the original f2, we then
    // deal with the conversion from [T]? to [SomeProtocol]? in the closure.
    // (and by "we", I mean the compiler, implicitly)
    f2(ofType: type, listener: { (arr: [T]?) in listener(arr) })
}
```

Allowing you to once again call it as `f2(ofType: A.self, listener: l2)`.

Comment: The problem is that in my real example I have 2 protocols - so I need dozens of overloads. That means that instead to having just one `func parseList<T: JsonInitable>(ofType type: T.Type, json: String, listener: ([T]?) -> Void) { return T(fromJson: json) }` I will need to have in addition several `func parseList<T: JsonInitable>(ofType type: T.Type, json: String, listener: ([BackendObj1ProtocolForUI]?) -> Void)` so that I can call `parseList(ofType: BackendObj1ImplClass.self, json: replyStr, listener: {(_: [BackendObj1ProtocolForUI]?, _: Error?) in })` for each BackendObj_N concept in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The listener closure in `func f2<T: SomeProtocol>(ofType: T.Type, listener: ([T]?) -> Void) {...}` requires its argument to be an array of `T`, where T is a type that implements `SomeProtocol`. By writing `<T: SomeProtocol>`, you are enforcing that **all** elements of that array are of the same type.

Say for example you have two classes: `A` and `B`. Both are completely distinct. Yet both implement `SomeProtocol`. In this case, the input array cannot be `[A(), B()]` because of the type constraint. The input array can either be `[A(), A()]` or `[B(), B()]`.

But, when you define `l2` as `let l2: ([SomeProtocol]?) -> Void = ...`, you allow the closure to accept an argument such as `[A(), B()]`. Hence this closure, and the closure you define in `f2` are incompatible and the compiler cannot convert between the two.

Unfortunately, you cannot add type enforcement to a variable such as `l2` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545220/is-it-possible-to-create-a-generic-closure-in-swift). What you can do is if you know that `l2` is going to work on arrays of class `A`, you could redefine it as follows:

```
let l2: ([A]?) -> Void = { ... }
```

Let me try and explain this with a simpler example. Let's say you write a generic function to find the greatest element in an array of comparables:

```
func greatest<T: Comparable>(array: [T]) -> T {
    // return greatest element in the array
}
```

Now if you try calling that function like so:

```
let comparables: [Comparable] = [1, "hello"]
print(greatest(array: comparables))
```

The compiler will complain since there is no way to compare an Int and a String. What you must instead do is follows:

```
let comparables: [Int] = [1, 5, 2]
print(greatest(array: comparables))
```

Comment: There's no (expected) incompatibility – you can pass a homogenous array with elements of type `T` to something expecting a heterogenous array of some supertype of `T`, i.e you can pass an `[A]` to something expecting a `[SomeProtocol]`. Doing so doesn't break any contracts.

Comment: @Hamish From the [swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID181):  "The placeholder type name doesn’t say anything about what T must be, but it does say that both a and b must be of the same type T, whatever T represents". So, when we say [T], it must be an array of all the same types.

Comment: Sure, but what I'm saying is that a `[T]` can be passed to something expecting a `[SomeProtocol]` given `T : SomeProtocol` :)

Comment: I absolutely agree. :) The problem is, the questioner is trying to do the reverse. He's passing a closure which accepts [SomeProtocol] when the function is expecting a closure which accepts [T].

Comment: But the types are in *parameter* positions, therefore you need to think of it in reverse :) Consider how `f2` would be calling `listener` – it's passing in an argument of type `[T]?` into a function expecting a `[SomeProtocol]?` parameter.

Comment: @Hamish yes, that's how I use it. I cannot break anything there in theory, the array I will pass to the listener will have objects of `SomeProtocol` type, it is guaranteed by the rest of the code I wrote, so most probably it is the compiler that is not "smart" enough to understand it.

Comment: Hmmm. But the closure declaration has `[T]`. If `[T]` were used directly as a parameter of `f2`, the "same-type" requirement would be enforced. Why would then the compiler relax that requirement for the closure?

Comment: @mohak what do you mean by same type? I can call `func f<T>(a: T, b: T)` with `f(a: A(), b: B())` if B inherits A.

Comment: @frangulyan Absolutely yes. By same-type I meant two distinct, non-related classes like an Int and a String.

Comment: @mohak I guess in case of a closure the logic is indeed reversed, as Hamish wrote. The question is - is it possible to also use that closure in a "direct logic" - if yes, then compiler is correct and cannot do anything, if no - then it should treat closures differently. The first example without an array argument in closure is already treated reversely so seems like the compiler just doesn't go too deep.

Comment: @frangulyan when I write `[T]`, even inside a closure, I would expect the elements to belong to the same type. If the array could contain any type that implements SomeProtocol, I would find that counter-intuitive or at leat a little confusing. I think for your purpose, Dominik's solution seems the best. It works and it's not confusing at all.

Comment: ok, the "reversed" logic is really misleading, an example makes it simpler to visualize - if `class B: A` and `var x: A = A(); var y: B = B()` and `var xx: (A) -> Void = {_ in }; var yy: (B) -> Void = {_ in }` then `x = y` **but** `yy = xx` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148706/discussion-between-mohak-and-frangulyan).

Answer (score 0):

Have nothing on Hamish's answer, he is 100% right. But if you wanna super simple solution without any explanation or code just work, when working with array of generics protocol, use this:

```
func f1<T: SomeProtocol>(ofType: T.Type, listener: (T?) -> Void) {
}

func f2<Z: SomeProtocol>(ofType: Z.Type, listener: ([SomeProtocol]?) -> Void) {
}
```