# Swift 4 - Generic Type Conversion issue - Cannot convert to expected type '(_) -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift, generics, type-conversion, swift4

I am using Xcode 9.2.

I am receiving the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(ValueType2) -> Void' to expected
>   argument type '(_) -> Void'

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

enum Value<ValueType> {

    case hasValue(ValueType)

}

class BaseClass<ValueType> {

    var value: Value<ValueType>?

    func f1<ValueType2>(closure: @escaping (ValueType, @escaping (ValueType2) -> Void) -> Void ){

        let s1 = SubClass<ValueType2>()

        // The point of the generic type conversion issue
        // Cannot convert value of type '(ValueType2) -> Void' to expected argument type '(_) -> Void'

        closure(value!, s1.f2)

    }

}

class SubClass<ValueType>: BaseClass<ValueType> {

    func f2(value: ValueType) -> Void { /* DO SOMETHING */ }

}
```

I am unsure whether this is related to the Swift bug being fixed in Swift 4.1:

[Swift Generics: Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991116/swift-generics-cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-expected-argument-type)

As autocomplete knows the class's correct generic type parameter & function's parameter - `ValueType2` - in both cases.

Any ideas on how to overcome this error?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like it might be an instance of that bug. If I replace all instances of `ValueType2` with a concrete type like `Int` the error goes away.

Comment: Just what I thought.

Comment: I also noticed that if I remove ValueType generic parameter from the f1(closure:) method, the compiler issue goes away. It seems the compiler does not like two generic types in a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `f2`, the type of `closure` is `@escaping (ValueType, @escaping (ValueType2) -> Void) -> Void`.

The type of the first parameter is `ValueType`.
But you are using it as:

```
closure(value!, s1.f2)
```

The type of the first argument `value!` is `Value<ValueType>`, not `ValueType`.

---

If you change the type of `closure` to `@escaping (Value<ValueType>, @escaping (ValueType2) -> Void) -> Void`, your code would compile without any issue.

You may have found some issue about generics, but at least, your code example is not describing the issue.

Comment: Perfect. I'd been staring at the answer for ages. Thank you!