# Swift error: "class cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers"

Tags: ios, swift

Xcode is giving me this error for my Swift code:

> 'myColor' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

```
import Foundation

protocol Prototype {
    func Clone<T>() -> T
}

class myColor: Prototype {
    var red: Int?
    var green: Int?
    var blue: Int?
    
    init () {}
    
    func Clone<myColor>() -> myColor {
        let newColor = myColor()
        newColor.red = self.red
        newColor.green = self.green
        newColor.blue = self.blue
        
        return newColor
    }
}
```

The error is on line:

```
let newColor = myColor()
```

> Type 'myColor' has no member 'init'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, classes have leading caps. Methods have leading lowercase. You mean `MyColor` and `clone()`.

You're confusing the compiler at this point:

```
func Clone<myColor>() -> myColor {
```

It thinks you mean that `myColor` is a type variable that is shadowing the class name. So when you get to `myColor()`, it's basically the same thing as `T()`, which has no trivial constructor.

If you fix this stuff up, you'll find that the correct error is

```
Type 'MyColor' does not conform to protocol 'Prototype'
```

*That* error is a completely different problem. See [Protocol func returning Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self) for an explanation of how to implement a copy protocol. You also may be interested in the followup: [Swift protocol and return types on global functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695091/swift-protocol-and-return-types-on-global-functions).

Answer (score 21):

Even if you set your framework to public, you still need to declare all classes you want to make accessible as 'public'. Same goes for your init method.

```
public init() {
}
```

Did the trick for me.

Comment: This solved this error message for me - the base class (in which I have overridden the default init) needed to be written as override public init()

Answer (score 1):

You will hit this error if you attempt to add a new property to a subclass without adding new initializers.

> 'SomeSubclass' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Suddenly none of the existing superclass's initializers will be valid, as the new variable needs to be set within an `init()` method on the subclass (which doesn't yet exist).

```
class SomeSubclass: UIViewController { // Class 'SomeSubclass' has no initializers

    var date: Date
    
    class func `for`(_ date: Date) -> SomeSubclass {
        let someSubclass = SomeSubclass() // 'SomeSubclass' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
        someSubclass.date = date
        return someSubclass
    }
        
}
```

A fix for most UIViewController situations, as is commonly used for `IBOutlets`, is to declare the subclass's properties as optionals or implicitly unwrapped optionals, which will be valid and initialized to `nil` when using the existing superclass init methods. Then set the value immediately after initialization.

```
var date: Date?
// - or - //
var date: Date!
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems generic generates extend of class, and need for use.

```
override init() {...
```

Note that any class in Swift must have initializer.
And in your case nevertheless generic, class must have **init()**