# Getting clone of superclass

Tags: swift, clone, subclass, superclass

Here is my playground snippet:

```
class Box {
  func clone() -> Box {
    return Box() // <- how to return superclass here?
  }
}

class VBox:Box { }

let vb = VBox()
let cBox = vb.clone() // now cBox is a Box, not a VBox
```

My `clone` function returns a `Box` class in all cases. But for the subclass I want it to return the superclass (so above it should return `VBox`).

I know I could `override` the `clone` function inside `VBox` but I wonder if there's a smarter way.

Comment: VBox is a *subclass* of Box, not a superclass. – This might be what you are looking for: [Protocol func returning Self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self)

Comment: Got the flu any my brain still feel hazy. You are right. So it looks like I need to make them NSObject and use NSCopying? - Ehrm. You changed the link on the fly?

Comment: *"Ehrm. You changed the link on the fly"* – Yes.

Comment: `NSCopying` is not the right tool for that. It is unsafe since it has to cast through `AnyObject`. `NSCopying` should only be used to interact with Cocoa. The right tool is to implement `init(copy:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean subclass. Box is the superclass, which is what you're returning.

This is very similar to the following:

- [Protocol func returning Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self)
- [Swift protocol and return types on global functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695091/swift-protocol-and-return-types-on-global-functions/25701421)

It's not exactly the same question, though, since you're dealing with classes rather than protocols, so we can go through that example. First, the right tool is `init`, not a `clone`:

```
class Box {
    let a: String
    init(_ a: String) { self.a = a }
    convenience init(copy: Box) { self.init(copy.a) }
}

class VBox:Box {}

let vb = VBox("test")
let cBox = VBox(copy: vb)
```

You see that this works fine since `VBox` adds no additional properties. But if `VBox` does add additional properties, then you'll get all the right errors that require you to implement an `init`.

```
class Box {
    let a: String
    init(_ a: String) { self.a = a }
    convenience init(copy: Box) { self.init(copy.a) }
}

class VBox:Box {
    let b: String
    init(_ a: String, _ b: String) {
        self.b = b
        super.init(a)
    }
    convenience init(copy: VBox) {
        self.init(copy.a, copy.b)
    }
}

let vb = VBox("test", "this")
let cBox = VBox(copy: vb)
```

Note how this prevents you from trying to copy a `Box` into a `VBox` (since that would not initialize all the parameters). If you want that to work, you'd need to provide a `copy(Box)` initializer. This is the nice thing about using `init`. It keeps track of all the rules for you. `NSCopying` would let you make that mistake and would eventually crash.

Comment: Sorry for the super/sub confusion (flu, see above comment :-) Martin's first comment led me to some NSObject thread. Later he edited it so it points to the first of your own links above (which I read meanwhile). Thanks for taking the time to adopt it to my needs. Much appreciated!