# Is there anyway I can avoid the use of what appears to be some "boilerplate" code?

Tags: swift, generics

I am starting with a function that looks like this:

```
    func getUser(command: APICommand, id: Int, handler: (apiResponse: APIResponse<User>) -> Void )  {
    let url = apiPath + "users/\(id)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET,  url, parameters: requestParameters)
        .responseObject { (a:NSURLRequest, b:NSHTTPURLResponse?, c:User?, d:AnyObject?, e:NSError? ) in
        let apiResponse = APIResponse(command: command,request: a, response: b, swiftObject: c, rawObject: d,  error: e)
        if AlamofireAPIRequestRepository.resultIsRetryableError(e, command: command) {
          println("retrying request")
          command.retry()
        } else {
          handler(apiResponse: apiResponse)
        }
    }
  }
```

I am going to have a number of functions that look very similar such as, `getUserList()` for example.

Looking at this I realized the entire Alamofire.request call is going to be pretty much boiler plate code.  The only difference will be the Type of argument c passed into the closure that gets called by the `responseObject()` method.  In this case it is `User?` , in the `getUserList()` method it will be `UserList?`

Is there any way I can make this more generic and avoid what appears to be just "boilerplate" code?
I Here is what I have tried.

```
  func alamofireGetRequest<T>(url: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?,
    command: APICommand, handler: (apiResponse: APIResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Void {

          Alamofire.request(.GET,  url, parameters: parameters)
            .responseObject { (a:NSURLRequest, b:NSHTTPURLResponse?, c:T?, d:AnyObject?, e:NSError? ) in
              let apiResponse = APIResponse(command: command,request: a, response: b, swiftObject: c, rawObject: d,  error: e)
              if AlamofireAPIRequestRepository.resultIsRetryableError(e, command: command) {
                println("retrying request")
                command.retry()
              } else {
                handler(apiResponse: apiResponse)
              }
          }
      }
```

but the compiler complains with:

> Cannot invoke 'responseObject' with an argument list of type
>   '((NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> _)'

and if I replace the c:T? above with c:User? it is happy.

A comment below referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401584/generics-as-parameters-to-a-closure-in-swift),  which may explain why the solution I tried does not work, but does really answer my intended question as to how to avoid this duplicated code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [generics as parameters to a closure in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401584/generics-as-parameters-to-a-closure-in-swift)

Comment: I edited my title,  since I am really looking for a way to avoid the duplicated code,  the question you point to _may_ explain why my attempted solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an acceptable solution.

Below is the relevant parts of the code, but basically I end up passing in an argument type of AnyObject in to the closure rather than a generic.  Before you say that I am cheating you have to understand that my original call would have looked something like this.

```
func testGetUserRequestSuccess() {
  let getUserCommand=commandFactory.createGetUserCommandUsing(apiRepo, id: 1) {
    if let swiftObject = $0.swiftObject {
      XCTAssertEqual(swiftObject.id!, 1, "id is correct")
    }
    self.expectation.fulfill()
  }
  commandProcessor.processCommand(getUserCommand)
  wait(5)
}
```

now it looks like this:

```
func testGetUserRequestSuccess() {
  let getUserCommand=commandFactory.createGetUserCommandUsing(apiRepo, id: 1) {
    if let swiftObject = $0.swiftObject as? User {
      XCTAssertEqual(swiftObject.id!, 1, "id is correct")
    }
    self.expectation.fulfill()
  }
  commandProcessor.processCommand(getUserCommand)
  wait(5)
}
```

so I had to add the `as? User`  cast to the `if let` statement, which seems reasonable.

### relevant code for anyone interested.

The "specialty" code (what will be repeated for each operation)

---

```
  func getUser(retriesUse retryProcessor: APICommandProcessor, command: APICommand, id: Int, handler: (apiResponse: APIResponse) -> Void )  {
    let url = apiPath + "users/\(id)"
    Alamofire.request(.GET,  url, parameters: requestParameters)
      .responseObject { (a:NSURLRequest, b:NSHTTPURLResponse?, c:User?, d:AnyObject?, e:NSError? ) in
        let apiResponse = APIResponse(command: command,request: a, response: b, swiftObject: c, rawObject: d,  error: e)
        self.finishResponse(command, retryProcessor: retryProcessor, apiResponse: apiResponse, handler: handler)
    } 
 }
```

---

The common part that I wanted to factor out (mainly a placeholder at this point)

```
func finishResponse(command: APICommand, retryProcessor: APICommandProcessor, apiResponse: APIResponse, handler: (apiResponse: APIResponse) -> Void) -> Void {
      if AlamofireAPIRequestRepository.resultIsRetryableError(apiResponse.error, retryProcessor: retryProcessor, command: command) {
        println("retrying \(command)")
        retryProcessor.retryCommand(command)
      } else {
        println("request completed")
        handler(apiResponse: apiResponse)
      }
  }
```

a supporting struct used above:

---

```
struct APIResponse {
  let command: APICommand
  let request: NSURLRequest
  let response: NSHTTPURLResponse?
  let swiftObject: AnyObject?
  let rawObject: AnyObject?
  let error: NSError?
}
```