# Swift generic function saved as varaible

Tags: swift, generics

Given a class:

```
class First<T> {

}
```

And a method of class First:

```
func second<U>(closure: (value: T) -> U) {

}
```

How could I store the closure passed as an argument to `second` so that I can call it at a later date?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401584/generics-as-parameters-to-a-closure-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to declare U in the class instead, so that you have a type for the storage:

```
class First<T,U> {
    var f : ((T) -> U)! = nil
    func second(closure: @escaping (T) -> U) {
        self.f = closure
    }
}
```

Comment: That's Swift 3: Xcode 8, seed 6. Note that your `value:` is now illegal, and that `@escaping` is needed to signify that this function is not for immediate execution.

Comment: Annoyingly this seems to be the only way to do it properly

Answer (score 1):

If having the function `second` work for only one kind of type is good enough for you, then Matt's answer is good.

```
class First<T, U> {
    typealias ClosureType = (value: T) -> U
    var savedClosure: ClosureType? = nil
    func second(closure: ClosureType) {
        savedClosure = closure
    }
}
```

That doesn't actually answer your question as stated!

The thing is: **You can't store a value of an unknown type.**
But! if the type conforms to a known protocol, then you can save it.

```
protocol P {}

class First<T> {
    typealias ClosureType = (value: T) -> P
    var savedClosure: ClosureType? = nil
    func second<U: P>(closure: (value: T) -> U) {
        savedClosure = closure
    }
}
```

The protocol could even be `protocol<>` "no protocol at all", which is typealiased to the keyword `Any`.

```
class First<T> {
    typealias ClosureType = (value: T) -> Any
    var savedClosure: ClosureType? = nil
    func second<U>(closure: (value: T) -> U) {
        savedClosure = closure
    }
}
```

But we don't really know what you want to do, so there are multiple answers to your question… for example, maybe you wanted to store a separate closure for each type?

```
class First<T> {
    typealias ClosureType = (value: T) -> Any
    var savedClosures = [String: ClosureType]()
    func second<U>(closure: (value: T) -> U) {
        savedClosures[String(U)] = closure
    }
}
```

Anyway, the real question is: "Do you really need to do this? Is there some simple change you can do that obviates this need?"

Comment: So the reason I want to save a closure with two generics in is to provide some mapping functionality. I.e. maps `T` to `U`. The problem with your solution is that every time I want to map say an `int` to a `string` id have to implement my own version of string that adheres to a protocol of type `P`. Upvote for creativity though!

Comment: You can use an empty extension `extension String: P {}`, but you don't need to if you use `Any`, as "all types implicitly conform" to it.