# Complex Swift closure with generic argument

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, closures

I have a scenario where I need to call a method with an optional closure argument where the closure receives a generic argument. Here's my simplified code:

```
class FooModel
{
}

class FooSubClass1 : FooModel
{
}

class FooSubClass2 : FooModel
{
}

class Client
{
    func httpGet<T:FooModel>(closure:((T) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        // Doing some network request stuff here and call onHTTPRequestComplete() when done!
        onHTTPRequestComplete(data: result, closure: closure)
    }

    func onHTTPRequestComplete<T:FooModel>(data:[String:Any], closure:((T) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        if let c = closure
        {
            switch(T)
            {
                case is FooSubClass1:
                    var foo = FooSubClass1()
                    // Process data into new FooSubClass1 object here!
                    c(foo)
                case is FooSubClass2:
                    var foo = FooSubClass2()
                    // Process data into new FooSubClass2 object here!
                    c(foo)
            }
        }
    }
}


class App
{
    func someFunc()
    {
        client.httpGet()
        {
            response in
            print("\(response)")
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here:
I have a data model with a super class and several subclasses. In `Client` I do http requests to retrieve data and want to populate model objects with the data retrieved. The calling method in `App` should be able to provide a closure that is called after the asynchronous network request is done and in which I get back the correct data model object.

There are several issues with my code:

`switch(T)`: Error: expected member name or constructor call after type name

`c(foo)`: Error: '(FooSubClass1) -> Void' is not convertible to '(T) -> Void'

Not sure my closure definition makes sense for what I'm trying to do.

**Updated code:**

```
protocol FooModel
{
    init()
}

class FooModelBase : FooModel
{
}

class FooSubClass1 : FooModelBase
{
}

class FooSubClass2 : FooModelBase
{
}

class Client
{
    func httpGet<T:FooModel>(closure:((T) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        // Doing some network request stuff here and call onHTTPRequestComplete() when done!
        onHTTPRequestComplete(data: result, closure: closure)
    }

    func onHTTPRequestComplete<T:FooModel>(data:[String:Any], closure:((T) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        if let c = closure
        {
            switch T.self
            {
                case is FooSubClass1.Type:
                    var foo = FooSubClass1()
                    // Assign retrieved values to model!
                    closure(foo)
                case is FooSubClass2.Type:
                    var foo = FooSubClass2()
                    // Assign retrieved values to model!
                    closure(foo)
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}


class App
{
    func someFunc()
    {
        client.httpGet()
        {
            response in
            print("\(response)") // Should output FooSubClass1 instance with assigned values!
        }
    }
}
```

Almost works but I get the following compile error:

```
'closure(foo): Error: '(@lvalue FooSubClass1) -> Void' is not convertible to '(T) -> Void'
```

Comment: This still will not work because your closure needs to take a generic T. You need something like `((FooModel) -> Void)?` instead (at this point you can get rid of the generics) but then in the closure you would have to appropriately cast it to whatever it's suppose to be. (Many ways to solve this, like passing in another parameter so you know what type it is, etc.)

Comment: @BadmintonCat If you find yourself writing a switch statement to handle the type of a generic parameter, you are defeating the entire purpose of generics, which is _abstraction_. The method that uses `T` must be able to take _any_ `T`, not just some narrow list you've defined inside the method. Rethink the whole thing, in my opinion.

Comment: Something minimal like this: https://pastebin.com/0WDWh1Cb

Comment: Also, your closure can never be `nil` because otherwise the compiler will not be able to figure out what the concrete type of `T` is. If you leave out the closure and say `onHTTPRequest(data: [:])`, what is `T`? Your code will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

for the `switch(T)` error of course you get this error. Because you're trying to switch a type but you should be switching a value. For your second error it makes perfect sense because then what would closure be expecting then because T is generic.

For more info on generics in closures have a look at this stackoverflow thread

[generics as parameters to a closure in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401584/generics-as-parameters-to-a-closure-in-swift)

All in all what you're trying to do there just isn't possible and at first glance I believe this isn't the correct direction to go in (Although I could be wrong without seeing the whole context). One thing you can do instead maybe is have your closure be `((Any) -> Void)?` but then unfortunately the type would be of `Any` and you would have to do a switch inside of the closure.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `T` in the closure will be passed to the closure itself. You can't switch on it. But what I think you want is to switch on the type. You could do something like this:

```
let type = String(reflecting: T.self)
switch (type) {
case "Module.FooSubClass1":
    var foo = FooSubClass1()
}
```

Or you could say:

```
if FooSubClass1.self == T.self {
  var foo = FooSubClass1();
} else if FooSubClass2.self == T.self { 
  var foo = FooSubClass2();
}
```

However, [this code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). You seem to want to use generics but then have a hardcoded set of classes inside your generic method, which half-defeats the entire purpose of generics. Why not just define `FooModel` as

```
protocol FooModel {
    init()
}
```

Then instead of your switch statement, just create one and pass it to your closure.

```
func onHTTPRequestComplete<T: FooModel>(data: [String: Any], closure: ((T) -> Void)? = nil) {
    guard let closure = closure else { return }
    closure(T())
}
```

Or why not create `T` *outside* of `onHTTPRequestComplete` and pass it?

```
onHTTPRequestComplete(data: data: model: FooSubClass1()) { model in
    // Do something awesome with `model` right here.
}
```

However, what I'd probably do is this:

```
func httpGet(callback: (([String: Any]) -> Void)? = nil) {
    // Do some network stuff and get the data
    callback?(data)
}
```

Then inside of `callback`, just create whatever type you want:

```
httpGet { data in
   let foo = FooSubClass1(data: data)
   // foo on you
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I thought I could go with a variant of your first and fourth code example. But the problem is now where does it get the concrete type of `T` from? I imagined if I define the concrete model type in the calling closure, it would figure it out from there but that seems not the case. The type of T in `onHTTPRequestComplete` will always evaluate as `FooModel`.

Comment: Nevermind! This works! I forgot to adapt the method signature of some methods that called in between.

Comment: Well, almost worked. Now i get another error: `closure(foo): Error: (@lvalue FooSubClass1) -> Void is not convertible to (T) -> Void`. I updated with new code above.

Comment: @BadmintonCat What is the intent of `closure`? Is it intended to be used _after_ `T` has been initialized? Or is it intended to be used in order to initialize `T`?