# How can use Protocol in closure?

Tags: swift

I got this closure in blew, now I want use `Numeric` protocol instead of `Double`, how I can do this?

```
let test: (Double) -> Double = { value in
    
    // some work ...
    
    return value
}
```

what I tried so far:

```
let test<T>: (T) -> T where T: Numeric = { value in
    
    // some work ...
    
    return value
}
```

Comment: This won't work since it's not a concrete type. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25549841/1144632

Comment: What you're describing is called *first-class polymorphism* or *impredicative polymorphism*. Swift doesn't support it. If you edit your question to explain why you want it, we might be able to help you find an alternative design.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem here is that generics in Swift are *invariant*. E.g. `Numeric<Double>` and `Numeric<Int>` are completely *unrelated* types.
Any reason why you can't convert this to a function instead?

```swift
import Foundation

func test<T: Numeric>(value: T) -> T {
    return value + 1
}

let a = test(value: 10)
print(a)
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the closure in a struct, like this answer, but at that point, just use a function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25407534/1144632